# Homebrew package install returns 403 error from downloads.sf.net

Tags: macos, git, homebrew

---

SOLUTION: I had followed some directions for setting up a remote git repository despite red flags going off in my head:

```
git config --global user.name "..."
git config --global user.email "..."
git config --global credential.helper oskeychain
```

I opened up the git config file:

```
git config --global --edit
```

and removed the offending entries. Works fine!

---

I'm using Homebrew 0.9.5 on OS X 10.9.2
I get the following error:

```
[01:33:37 29] $ brew install gfortran r
==> Downloading https://downloads.sf.net/project/machomebrew/Bot
######################################################################## 100.0%
curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 403 LoginPagePost
Error: Failed to download resource "gfortran"
Download failed: https://downloads.sf.net/project/machomebrew/Bottles/gfortran-4.8.2.mavericks.bottle.1.tar.gz
Warning: Bottle installation failed: building from source.
==> Downloading http://ftpmirror.gnu.org/gcc/gcc-4.8.2/gcc-4.8.2
######################################################################## 100.0%
curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 403 LoginPagePost
Trying a mirror...
==> Downloading http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/gcc/gcc-4.8.2/gcc-4.8.2.t
######################################################################## 100.0%
curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 403 LoginPagePost
Error: Failed to download resource "gfortran"
Download failed: http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/gcc/gcc-4.8.2/gcc-4.8.2.tar.bz2
```

Comment: Found the solution, but have to wait 8 hours to answer it myself.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

SOLUTION: I had followed some directions for setting up a remote git repository despite red flags going off in my head:

```
git config --global user.name "..."
git config --global user.email "..."
git config --global credential.helper oskeychain
```

I opened up the git config file:

```
git config --global --edit
```

and removed the offending entries. Works fine!